# Best way to encode list names in sharepoint 2013 rest url's?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest

In SharePoint 2013 rest url's, some of them includes a list name which is passed by a user (in the web part settings) which I then use in a web part. I then stick the list name in a rest url, but now I realize that what if the user names the list with special characters like an apostrophe or with an & sign or something. What is the best way I can encode/fix the list name before sticking it in the rest url?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go with the regular Javascript [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

From the page linked to:

> The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a Uniform Resource
>   Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain
>   characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing
>   the UTF-8 encoding of the character. ... To avoid unexpected requests
>   to the server, you should call encodeURIComponent on any user-entered
>   parameters that will be passed as part of a URI.